# Silverlight 5 vector printing issue - weird characters on copy and paste

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I've just upgraded a silverlight application to SL5 mainly for take advantages of the new vector printing features.
It seems to work perfectly. Infact if i print to a PDF Creator i can select the text inside (in SL4 all were printed as raster).

But if i try to copy and paste the selected text to a notepad i get weird characters.

I have the same issue with a small test application with a print button and the following code behind:

```
  StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
  TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
  tb.Text = "Hello World!";      
  panel.Children.Add(tb);

  PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
  document.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
  {
    e.PageVisual = panel;
    e.HasMorePages = false;
  };

  PrinterFallbackSettings settings = new PrinterFallbackSettings();
  settings.ForceVector = true;      
  document.Print("Silverlight Printing Test", settings);
```

Comment: How do you copy? It may be as expected, as Postscript is not meant to be human readable.

Comment: i open the generated pdf file with acrobat reader, select some words of text and copy/paste to a notepad.

Comment: Same here - seems that few people actually use that api. I'd be very interested in a solution to this.